# Query speed while reading or writing

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I know we can index our columns in tables, defining primary keys, partitioning to access faster to data.

But is there any different in reading from a table which has 10 columns and a table with 100 columns?
could someone explain how database reading could be faster?

Comment: what is your actual problem? You can't generally substitute a 10 column table for a 100 column table.

Comment: But yes, if you are returning more data, it is usually slower. However the data types and whether they are filled or not can make a differnce in whteher the 10 column table is faster or slwoer than the 100 column table. Not that it matters since they should not directly substitute anyway. If you need 100 columns, you need 100 columns. Not the real question might be if the 100 column table shoudl be changes to a parent child table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading data involves: possible index access, row location in storage, physical io between disk, buffer, as well as performing formatting operations and functions on the fetched data. IO speed is data size dependent (among other factors such as block size, disk speed, buffer size, etc.)

The more data you request, the slower the process is in general. if you have a row with 2 integers, it will be faster to read 1000 such rows that reading the same number of rows from a table with 2 Varchar2(500) rows (filled with data).  Also reading 1000 rows with 2 columns is faster than reading a row with 100 column.

If you give more details you may get a more specific answer.

Comment: I just want to select only one column ( for example id ) , from a table with 10 cols and a table with 100 cols, is there any difference ?

Comment: Yes, selecting the one column is probably faster as the database will be able to fill the buffer with more rows with each I/O. That is one reason why SELECT * FROM ... is not recommended.

Comment: I know that, I mean which one of these are better : `select name from table ( with 100 columns )` OR `select (name) from table ( with 1000 columns )`. We're gonna select one column from both tables

Comment: The table's total row size also affects the speed. So I think that selecting 1 column from a short row is faster than selecting 1 column from a long row - See: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/whats-the-point-of-using-varchar%28n%29-anymore/

Comment: omg, Mr Emmad, I am talking about selecting just one column from a tables with more columns... not more rows.

Comment: My understanding is that total row size affects performance even if you are selecting 1 column. No need for the 'omg' part!